# Detect linear vs non linear filter

Tags: image-processing

I see that there are many available filters such as Median filter, Laplacian filter, Gradient filter... How can we distinguish whether they are a linear or non linear filter ?

 Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linear systems exhibit the following properties:

- Superposition
- Homogeneity of degree 1

To understand [superposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle) in images, consider a Gaussian filter operating on `n` regions of the image. If you apply the Gaussian on each of the `n` regions separately and add up the resulting values, the sum will be the same as when you add up the values in the `n` regions pixel-wise and apply the Gaussian just once. However this *does not always hold true* when you apply a median filter, because the median filter is chosen after re-ordering the pixels within the region.

To understand [homogeneity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function) in images, consider again a Gaussian filter operating on a single region in the image. Apply the Gaussian filter and obtain a resultant value `p`. Now within the region, multiply every pixel by a constant `c` and re-apply the same Gaussian filter to obtain resultant value `q`. You will find that `q = c * p`. This *does not always hold true* for the median filter.

As a quick test, if the filtering stage involves some modification to the image region being operated upon (including ordering), then the filter is a non-linear one. As a less quick test, apply the principles of superposition and homogeneity to classify the filter.